# Conditionally add table n+1 table rows (<tr>) in React

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm having problems dynamically adding jsx table rows to a table in react.

The case I have is the following:

*If a table row contains sub rows, add them in addition to the main row.*

This was my initial design:

```
        {rows.map((row) => {
        const expanded = _.includes(expandedRows, row.name); // check if row is expanded or not
        const subRows = row.subRows && row.subRows.map((subRow) =>
          <SubRow key={subRow.name} theme={theme} subRow={subRow.name} />);

        return (
          <div>
            <Row
              key={row.name}
              theme={theme}
              handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
              handleExpandOrCollapseRow={handleExpandOrCollapseRow}
            />
            {expanded && row.subRows && subRows}
            {expanded && !row.subRows && <p>No subrows exist</p>}
          </div>
        );
      })
```

The problem is that div is not allowed as child in the tbody tag. Any ideas how I can get around this without wrapping my return in a div?

I was thinking to move the whole tbody to my Row component and conditionally render the subrows there, but I can't see how it would help since I still can't use any wrapper around the return... the only wrapper I can use is tbody and that can only occur once as parent to all rows.

Any idea?

Comment: why don't you wrap your code with a `tbody` instead of a `div` and remove the `tbody` from the parent ?

Comment: @oliv37 because then it would render a tbody for each loop. i.e. each tr (and possibly subrows) would be wrapped with tbody.

Comment: so why don't you add the subrows in the loop in the parent component ?

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the example provided if I'm understanding you correctly. The snippet I showed is from the parent component which renders a table. The snippet concerns everything inside tbody which is a number of rows. The problem is that in some loops of the map function I want to render 1 + x number of rows and I can't wrap them in anything.

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you and should explain more.

Comment: I give you a possible solution, for each step of the loop (in the map function) instead of returning a Component, you return an array of Component containing a Row and maybe some subrows. As a result you get an array of array, you can then flatten this result to display an array of components

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend @oliv37 approach. In fact, I've added an answer using this method, as I do the same in my react projects.

Comment: This is maybe simpler to use a for loop instead of a map. In the **for loop** you can do `result.add(<Row ...>)` then `result.add(subrow)` for each subrows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead returning a wrapped `div` around multipls `tr`'s, you can simple collect the `rows` in an `array` and then return the `array` afterwards.

### Here's an example

```
renderTableRows() {
    const rows = [];

    // Push the main row first
    rows.push(
        <Row
            key={row.name}
            theme={theme}
            handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
            handleExpandOrCollapseRow={handleExpandOrCollapseRow}
        />
    );

    // Then push the subrows
    row.subRows.forEach(subRow =>
        rows.push(
            <SubRow key={subRow.name} theme={theme} subRow={subRow.name} />
        );
    );

    return rows;
}
```

### Then add the renderTableRows() method to your view like this

```
render() {
    if( this.state.isLoading ) {
        return Table.renderSpinner();
    }

    return (
        <table>
            { this.renderTableRows() }
        </table>
    );
}
```

I can't say for sure if that code will work for you out of the box. But this pattern should help you to solve your problem.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for the help, you as well @oliv37. 

This is the "finished" piece of code: https://pastebin.com/eeCi1DYZ

It contains some domain-specific stuff from my application but it should be clear enough I think.